# does chronic have any options of date format it parses? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, date, chronic

I need to tell chronic that the format of date is day-month-year is that possible? The data I pass to chronic could also be words today/yesterday/2 days ago.

Currently chronic gives me `2 Dec 2010` instead of `12 Feb 2010` from `12-02-2010`

*The only solution I can think of is to swap day and month before passing the string to chronic.*

```
require 'chronic'   

puts "12-02-2010 = #{Chronic.parse('12-02-2010')}"  #should be 12 Feb 2010


puts "yesteday = #{Chronic.parse('yesterday')}" #working ok
puts "Today = #{Chronic.parse('today')}"        #working ok
```

Comment: may be you would consider selecting my answer as the best answer :)

Comment: Thanks you for selecting my answer as the best answer :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found this question today, 20 months after it has been asked. It seems that there is a way to indicate to swap months and days. Just use the `:endian_precedence` option:

> :endian_precedence (Array) — default: [:middle, :little] — By default,
>   Chronic will parse "03/04/2011" as the fourth day of the third month.
>   Alternatively you can tell Chronic to parse this as the third day of
>   the fourth month by altering the `:endian_precedence` to `[:little,
>   :middle]`

Example here:

```
Chronic.parse('12-02-2010').strftime('%d %b %Y')   #=> 02 Dec 2010 
Chronic.parse('12-02-2010', :endian_precedence => [:little, :median]).strftime('%d %b %Y') #=> 12 Feb 2010
```

Hope this helps!

Dorian

Comment: Just what i was looking for.

Comment: One problem I'm finding is that it looks like Chronic will return a date in a different format if it can't format the way you're asking for.  e.g. 
    Chronic.parse('13/9/14', endian_precedence: [:middle, :little]) will still return September 13th, 2014, rather than failing to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

The output of chronic can be easily formatted. `chronic.parse` returns a time object.  You can use `strftime` for formatting as described [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298).

```
puts Chronic.parse('today').strftime('%d %b %Y') #=> 23 Feb 2010
```

As far as the input is concerned, I cannot find anything in chronic that will do it automatically.  Manipulating the input string is probably the way to go.

Edit:  Chronic has an internal `pre_normalize` that you could over-ride..

require 'chronic'

```
puts Chronic.parse('12-02-2010').strftime('%d %b %Y') #=> 02 Dec 2010

module Chronic
  class << self
    alias chronic__pre_normalize pre_normalize  

    def pre_normalize(text)
      text = text.split(/[^\d]/).reverse.join("-") if text =~ /^\d{1,2}[^\d]\d{1,2}[^\d]\d{4}$/
      text = chronic__pre_normalize(text)
      return text
    end
  end
end
puts Chronic.parse('12-02-2010').strftime('%d %b %Y') #=> 12 Feb 2010
```

Comment: things have changed since this answer was given. see my answer for the up to date solution to this question