# How to convert a text date to a scoped Date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies if the title is not clear, I' not really sure how to explain this clearly.

In a Rails app I'm pulling in users' data from a 3rd party provider's API. One of the attributes is the user's birthday.

I am storing the hashed data in my database and, in certain circumstances, need to display the user's birthday in the view.

The problem is that the birthday is not formatted as a Date. Within the hash, it is in the format mm/dd/yyyy. This means that my usual date scoped formats don't work on it.

Given that I am extracting the birthday from the hashed data column as follows

```
<%= @user.hashed_data["info"]["birthday"] %>
```

what is the best/ most efficient way to handle this so that I can display localized date formats?

Do I need to split on the `/` symbols, and then recombine the resulting string to a date? Or am  I overcomplicating this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Would you / could you consider converting the string to a proper date at the point of receiving it from the 3rd party API and storing it in your DB as such?

Comment: would consider it, but I'm storing the complete token, so may be rather complicated to extract this attribute, manipulate it, the put it back. jdoe's solution does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Date.strptime('01/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') 
# => #<Date: 2011-01-31 (4911185/2,0,2299161)>
```

Comment: nice! work's a treat. Thanks for showing me this, very useful

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to convert plain text to date or datetime is to use the [chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

A very usefull parameter that you can pass to the chronic parser is the `:endian_precedence` . See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317569/does-chronic-have-any-options-of-date-format-it-parses-ruby/7931246#7931246) for more details.

Regards, Dorian