# Trying to validate a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form where i'm trying to validate that a field called "birthday" is not blank, and that the date is a valid date format that the Chronic gem can parse. I always get the error message "Birthday is invalid". I've been trying a simple format "10/10/2010".

How can i validate that the birthday field is of a format that chronic can parse?

User.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :birthday, :presence => true
  validate :birthday_is_date
  validate :position, :presence => true

  # validate the birthday format
  def birthday_is_date
    errors.add(:birthday ,Chronic.parse(birthday)) # testing to see the value of :birthday
    errors.add(:birthday, "is invalid test message") if ((Chronic.parse(:birthday) rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
# POST /contacts/1/edit
    # actually updates the users data
    def update_user
        @userProfile = User.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @userProfile.update_attributes(params[:user])
                format.html {
                    flash[:success] = "Information updated successfully"
                    redirect_to(profile_path)
                }
            else 
                format.html {
                    flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages

                    render :edit
                }
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Well, you've got `:birthday` (a symbol) in your validation instead of `birthday` (a variable). That might well cause the problem.

Comment: Birthday is a "DATE" field in the db if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `birthday_is_date` validation always adds an error on the first line. It should be written as follows:

```
def birthday_is_date
  errors.add(:birthday, "is invalid") unless Chronic.parse(birthday)
end
```

Comment: I tried this, but if i use `01/01/1985` as a date, I get the error "Birthday is invalid"

Comment: Nevermind that works, but 03/20/1985 does not working, because the month/day are backwards than what it expects. Can i set this to look for mm/dd/yyyy rather than dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: It seems the answer to my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317569/does-chronic-have-any-options-of-date-format-it-parses-ruby.

Answer (score 1):

try this

install [**validates_date_time**](https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/validates_date_time) gem

you can pass validation for date, **`for example`**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_date     :date_of_birth
    validates_time     :time_of_birth
    validates_date_time :date_and_time_of_birth
  end
```

Use :allow_nil to allow the value to be blank.

```
  class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_date :date_of_birth, :allow_nil => true
  end
```

**Source** : https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/validates_date_time

Answer (score 1):

From [chronic.rubyforge.org](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/):

> Chronic uses Ruby’s built in Time class for all time storage and
>   computation. Because of this, only times that the Time class can
>   handle will be properly parsed. Parsing for times outside of this
>   range will simply return nil. Support for a wider range of times is
>   planned for a future release.
>
> Time zones other than the local one are not currently supported.
>   Support for other time zones is planned for a future release.

From [Date validation in Ruby using the Date object](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/date-validation-in-ruby-using-date.html):

> A simple validate function
>
> One way to test for a valid date is to try to create a Date object. If
>   the object is created, the date is valid, and if not, the date is
>   invalid. Here is a function that accepts year, month, and day, then
>   returns true if the date is valid and false if the date is invalid.

```
def test_date(yyyy, mm, dd)
   begin
     @mydate = Date.new(yyyy, mm, dd)
     return true
   rescue ArgumentError
     return false
   end
 end
```

From [the accepted answer of How do I validate a date in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails):

> If you're looking for a plugin solution, I'd checkout the
>   validates_timeliness plugin. It works like this (from the github
>   page):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_date :date_of_birth, :on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }
  # or
  validates :date_of_birth, :timeliness => {:on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }, :type => :date}
end
```

> The list of validation methods available are as follows:
>
> validates_date     - validate value as date
>   validates_time     - validate value as time only i.e. '12:20pm'
>   validates_datetime - validate value as a full date and time
>   validates          - use the :timeliness key and set the type in the hash.

Comment: I tried `validates :date_of_birth, :timeliness => {:on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }, :type => :date}` and i still get "Birthday is not a valid date"